# How to create simple web server with HTTP/1.0 protocol in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I've homework for Client Server Programming course and it want me to create Multi-Client Web Servers. But the rule is web server must implement HTTP version 1.0 protocol, where separated HTTP requests are sent for each component of the Web Page.
Unfortunately, I'm just know to work with Node.js. I know C, but it long times (around 10 years ago) and only do very basic programming such as arithmetic operation, work with string and arrays, not OOP in C.

So the question, how to create web server with HTTP/1.0 protocol in Node.js?

Currently, I have node v.10.15.1 installed on my laptop (using macos). I've tried with http and net module but can't find how to configure the protocol to use HTTP/1.0

Comment: I guess the point of your homework is implementing a http server yourself. Using Node.js modules like `http` would count as cheating anyway

Comment: If sending a separate request is the only important requirement for HTTP 1.1 over 1.0, you could use node to implement the 1.1 server but return `Connection: close` header with every response so that the browser doesn't keep its connection live but instead is forced to establish a new connection for each resource.

Comment: @pete ofc for real source code i'm not using `http` module, instead will use `net`

Comment: @WiktorZychla so basically setup the response to have `Connection: close` header will implement HTTP/1.0 behavior? Do my request from client also must specify that `Connection: close` header?
Thanks for the answer anyway, will try it!

Comment: @MuhammadIzzuddinAlFikri: the client (browser) doesn't have to specify anything extra (plus: you can't really control what the browser does). It's only that in HTTP 1.1 the keep-alive is default so that you have to turn it off in an explicit way. Not that I wonder why would your tutor pay any attention to this particular element of the communication.

Comment: @WiktorZychla sorry, in this case the client can be cli or just curl command from terminal. Or maybe another script so I can hardcoded it.
Actually this is homework for make me (and other students) really understand behind the scene of how communication happen. The course not meant to create some sophisticate application, goal is science oriented.
If there's no way to do this on node, maybe I must change to C or python or .NET?

Comment: @MuhammadIzzuddinAlFikri: I guess the most fair approach would be to just ask your tutor if they would accept a node.js based HTTP 1.1 server or rather they expect a lower level approach.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I think it's not possible, because my position is as student (Graduate level) and actually there are many details on this homework that must to do using HTTP/1.0 to reach the goal. I will move to another language then if can't do this on node and it will be the most fair approach. Thanks anyway for your answer.

Answer (score -3):

We need to require the **http module** first and bind our server to the **port** which we listen on.
Inside the **index.js** :

```
    // content of index.js
const http = require('http')
const port = 3000

const requestHandler = (request, response) => {
  console.log(request.url)
  response.end('Hello Its Your Node.js Server!')
}

const server = http.createServer(requestHandler)

server.listen(port, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('something bad happened', err)
  }

  console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`)
})
```

So lets start it with:

```
$ node index.js
```

Comment: When I ran that code it responded to my HTTP 1.0 formatted request with `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`